# Microsoft Word 2012 Content Controls: Group on multiple table rows

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I was trying to add a Rich Text Content Control or a Group around multiple lines of a Word table in order to achieve a master-detail view where I can have multiple master rows and show details in sub rows.

Is there any way to put such content controls around multiple rows with MS Word or should I use nested tables(at least try to).

At this stage adding them by code is not an option.

Thanks

EDIT: Apparently you can only use a single row or the entire table, even if clearly the header row shouldn't be repeated!

Comment: Word 2010 user interface only seems to let you wrap a content control around a single row.  However, if you edit the XML to wrap it around two rows, on a quick test Word 2010 does open the docx, and display the content control wrapped around those 2 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Microsoft Word 2013 a new type of control has been added i.e. Repeating Section Content Control.
It exactly meets your requirements. You can read more about it @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838936(v=office.15) under Enhancement to content controls section.